# jQuery function on element click doesnt work only from external file

Tags: jquery, html, file, external

I have html element with id:

```
<img id = "ShowOrHideImage" src="~/Images/show_expander.png"/>
```

when I place script to to html, I can get message after click:

```
<script>
    $("#ShowOrHideImage").click(function () {
        alert("function invoked");
    });
</script>
```

But when I put script to external file MyScript.js:

```
alert("Script is there");

$("#ShowOrHideImage").click(function () {
    alert("function invoked");
});
```

I get message "Script is there" but never "function invoked"
I don't know what is the reason. Any ideas? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `external` javascript file would be loading before the element of `DOM` become available using `document.ready`. Also make sure the `jQuery` file is inlcluded before external javascript file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#ShowOrHideImage").click(function () {
      alert("function invoked");
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fastest working response I have ever get. +

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alert("Script is there");

$(function () {
  $("#ShowOrHideImage").click(function () {
    alert("function invoked");
  });
});
```

`$(function() {` is just an abbreviation for `$(document).ready(function () {`.

Also, the reason it worked embedded in your document is because you put it in the `<body>` tag, I presume, somewhere behind all the content (or not). If you embedded it in the `<head>` tag, it still will not work, and need `$(function () {`.

Comment: @vlkpo No worries, glad to help, even more glad to have helped.